# Есть ли альтернатива нагромождению проверки на NULL в SQL запросе?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ситуация, когда необходимо сделать запрос в таблицу по нескольким параметрам.
Например:

У нас есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
  Id BIGINT IDENTITY,
  Col1 BIGINT NULL,
  Col2 BIGINT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2) VALUES (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, NULL);
```

И процедура, которая возвращает из таблицы строку по параметрам:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
  @Prm1 BIGINT,
  @Prm2 BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Table1 t WHERE t.Col1 = @Prm1 AND t.Col2 = @Prm2
END
GO
```

Проблемы нет, пока мы не пытаемся вытянуть строку, имеющую в своём составе колонку со значением NULL. Но если мы решили это сделать, то данная процедура нам ничего не вернёт, потому что `NULL <> NULL`, и, соответственно, нам придётся переписать запрос, например так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
  @Prm1 BIGINT,
  @Prm2 BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Table1 t
    WHERE t.Col1 = @Prm1 AND t.Col2 = @Prm2 OR
      t.Col1 IS NULL AND @Prm1 IS NULL AND t.Col2 = @Prm2 OR
      t.Col2 IS NULL AND @Prm2 IS NULL AND t.Col1 = @Prm1 OR
      t.Col1 IS NULL AND @Prm1 IS NULL AND t.Col2 IS NULL AND @Prm2 IS NULL
END
GO
```

А можно ли как-то обойти это нагромождение сравнения данных с NULL в запросе, чтоб при этом сохранилась работоспособность запроса? Ведь если столбцов в таблице будет больше 2-х, и, соответственно, параметров в процедуре GetData, то условие в запросе очень сильно разрастается, что может приводить к появлению ошибок

Comment: Как минимум, последнее условие можно сократить до `COALESCE(t.Col1, @Prm1, t.Col2, @Prm2) IS NULL`.

Comment: `COALESCE(Col1, -1) = COLASCE(@Prm1, -1) AND COALESCE(Col2, -1) = COLASCE(@Prm2, -1)` Вместо -1 какое нибудь значение которого не может быть в данных и в запросе. Надеюсь такое есть. Хотя там можно и текстовое значение любое написать. будет конвертация чисел к строке, зато такстового значения в данных точно не будет

Comment: Увы, Null-safe compare в SQL Server не реализовано. А любое "причёсывание" `WHERE ((field = @param) OR (field IS NULL AND @param IS NULL))` с использованием функций с гарантией скажется отрицательно на производительности.